# Find and replace between two text files

Tags: python, txt

I have two .txt files
File1.txt
File2.txt

Say file1 contains:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
```

file 2 contains:

```
text2_b
text3_c
text5_f
text4_d
text1_a
```

Is there a way to find lines from file1 and replace them with matches from file2?

So for example, i'd get a file3.txt that contains the result which would be:
file3:

```
text1_a
text2_b
text3_c
text4_d
text5_f
```

I thought of using grep but i'm unsure how it's done

Comment: Please elaborate on your tries, what did you try to do so far with python or grep? what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Probably over simplified - but this is the obvious bash command set

```
cat file1 | while read n; do grep $n file2; done > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the python tag, a sample solution in Python can be as follows:

```
    # Open File1 for reading
    file1 = open('File1.txt', 'r')
    linesFile1 = file1.readlines()
    
    # Open File2 for reading
    file2 = open('File2.txt', 'r')
    linesFile2= file2.readlines()
    
    # Open file3 for writing the results
    file3 = open('file3.txt', 'w')
    
    # Search the text
    for lineFile1 in linesFile1:
        lineFile1Stripped = lineFile1.strip()
        for lineFile2 in linesFile2:
            lineFile2Stripped = lineFile2.strip()
            if lineFile1Stripped in lineFile2Stripped:
                file3.writelines(lineFile2Stripped + "\n")
    
    file1.close()
    file2.close()
    file3.close()
```